# linux — Is it possible (and safe?) to replace root partition via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh

Imagine you have a VPS on a cloud and want to completely replace the operating system originally installed. Given that you have prepared a complete root filesystem image, it is possible to roll it out like the following:

```
cat rootfs-image.bin.gz | ssh root@remotehost 'gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda1'
```

Is this a reliable solution (or, at very least, going to work) besides the fact that every sudden network failure will make it necessary to recreate the server?

Will the pipe of `sshd`, `bash`, `gunzip`, and `dd` processes operate properly when their executable files and shared libraries are getting overwritten on the level of block device, or this idea is doomed from the very beginning?

Comment: Yikes. You might consider something like [takeover](https://github.com/marcan/takeover.sh). At the very least it would grant you more than one chance at writing the partition.

Comment: @jscott: thank you for letting me know there exists a special tool for that.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past taking an image of a partition and then using nc piped through dd on both ends. It worked fine.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. To do this manually, the "best" way to do this would be to use [pivot_root](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pivot_root) to chroot into an area that does not live on the target partition and use that as your temporary space while wiping the target partition (this is almost certainly what takeover does).  See also [this unix.se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226872/how-to-shrink-root-filesystem-without-booting-a-livecd/227318#227318 "How to shrink root filesystem without booting a livecd"). You'll definitely want to cross your fingers when you reboot!

Comment: @AdamKatz: Thank you for pointing me to such a great, detailed answer. The `pivot_root` approach actually worked for me. However, it's pretty hard to automate.